# Transfering mysql table to an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have to fetch a table containing a couple of millions records with two columns - `id` and `name`, for each name make an explode operation, and then each exploded element save into the file along with its ID. The `id-keyword` pairs have to be unique.

What's the fastest, and most memory-efficient way to do that?

I've been thinking about something like this:

```
$query = $pdo -> prepare('SELECT id, name FROM table');
$query -> execute();

$time = microtime(true);

if (file_exists('test.txt')) {
        unlink('test.txt');
}
$fh = fopen('test.txt', 'a');
while ($result = $query -> fetch()) {
      $tokens = explode(" ", $result['name']);
      foreach ($tokens as $token) {
           fwrite($fh, $result['id'] . ' ' . $token . PHP_EOL);
      }
}
fclose($fh);

echo microtime(true) - $time;
```

1. But it takes over 15 seconds to achieve that, which is way to long, and the array is not unique.
2. I could also create an array with words as keys, containing array of ids as keys, which would solve the uniqness problem, but the whole structure would certainly be too big to fit into the memory, and in reasonable time.
3. I could create arrays upto a couple of records and perform `fwrite` from time to time, but then again, the rows would not be unique.

I don't want to do this on the database layer - the less DB logic the better, and I don't want to perform more heavy DB operations either.

How else could I do this?

Comment: Why are you exploding the name on spaces? That is how you are introducing duplicate rows in your file. Note that you are not even using your `$token` variable in the inner loop. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, I edited the code. I'm trying to fetch the array containing all single words from column name with corresponding name's ID, without duplicates.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do; you can easily filter `$tokens` so that all id-word combinations would be unique (assuming the id is unique to begin with...) and you could keep track of which records have been processed so that you would only have to do it once.

Comment: I couldn't do that, becuase creating that big array uses up too much memory, and takes way too long.

Comment: This should be a one-time operation to fix your messed up db design....so why does it matter if it takes 15 seconds?

Comment: Because - I do other things that need memory in the meantime, and I want to execute it once every day.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to speed this up to `1,5s` by appending results in chunks to string, and once in a while writing it to file, clearing that string.

```
    $query = $pdo -> prepare('SELECT id, name FROM table');
    $query -> execute();
    $fh = fopen('test.txt', 'a');
    $str = '';
    while ($result = $query -> fetch()) {
            $tokens = array_unique(explode(" ", $result['name']));
            foreach ($tokens as $token) {
                    $str .= $result['id'] . " " . $token . "\n";
            }
            if (strlen($str) > 5000) {
                    fwrite($fh, $str);
                    $str = '';
            }
    }
    fclose($fh);
```

Too frequent `fwrite`'s, or too long strings, make execution time longer, I guess it depends on my memory speed.